# save downloaded file automatically in directory using AIR

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, file, air

i'm newbie, so please help me...

```
package com.func {
    public class Downloader {
        import flash.net.FileReference;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;

        private var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        private var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
        public function Downloader(){
        }

        public function download():void{
            req.url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/example.txt";
            fr.download(req);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a fw questions:
1. how to save downloaded file automatically in file system directory (ex: applicationDirectory as default), **without open browse dialog to save the file**.
2. how to open that files after download complete into a textarea without save the file to filesystem first....
thaks....

Answer (score 0):

Data from a url can be downloaded using a [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLLoader.html). You can get a String from this in the complete event handler.

The string can then be set as the text property of the TextArea.

You can write to a file, without user interaction, using Air's [FileStream](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) class. The same class can also be used to read the file.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Sample code for URLLoader is in the linked docs. For filesteam, see: http://www.insideria.com/2008/03/beginning-air-accessing-the-fi-1.html

Comment: actually no.1 : save downloaded file automatically in file system (directory have been determined, ex:applicationDirectory), without open browse dialog to save the file.
thanks alot